# How to find the server ip from a public website?

Tags: networking, server, dns, ip, amazon-elb

Is there any command to find out the server IP instead of load balancer IP or proxy IP for any website?
Why can't we connect to few server IP directly. What config or setting is blocking us to connect using IP and what is the need of disabling this feature?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is difficult to answer because you are asking many different questions without explaining your particular configuration. Are you referring to an application that you have built, or are you referring to all websites on the Internet? Please edit your question to provide specific details of your system and what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: I'm referring to any common website in the internet.

Comment: The real server IP behind the load balancer IP could as well be in a private range not reachable directly from the Internet. What is your purpose exactly when trying to bypass the load balancer? Also since your question is not related to programming, it is offtopic here.

Answer (score 1):

Best-practice for both security and load balancing is typically:

- Expose the **Load Balancer** to the Internet
- Put servers behind a **firewall** so that they are not directly accessible
- Configure the Load Balancer to send traffic to the servers

The benefits are:

- **Minimum surface area** exposed to the Internet (limits potential security problems)
- Allows servers to be added/removed **without impacting end users** since they all connect via the Load Balancer (but the Load Balancer will need to know when servers are being added/removed)
- Ensures that **requests are balanced** between the servers rather than allowing end users to directly access a server